# TypeScript: extend keys with custom validation values

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm trying to extend class keys and set custom values for validation.

```
class FindUserDto {

  readonly _id?: string | object;
  readonly email?: string;
  readonly firstName?: string;
  readonly lastName?: string;
}
```

What I need is to create `SortBy` class that should take keys from the `FindUserDto` and validate `'ASC'` or `'DESC'` as incoming values. Something like this.

```
class SortBy {
  readonly email: 'ASC' | 'DESC';
  readonly firstName: 'ASC' | 'DESC';
  readonly lastName: 'ASC' | 'DESC';
}
```

But I want to avoid copying and pasting, that's why I'm fighting with typescript to deal with it.

I tried to set keys dynamically like this `[K in keyof FindUserDto]` or this `[key: K]` where `K extends {[T in keyof FindUserDto]}` but it doesn't work. Typescript doesn't allow such flow to be implemented.

The simplest solution for now is to upgrade the `FindUserDto` class by passing types inside:

```
class FindUserDto<T>{
  _id?: T;
  readonly email?: T;
  readonly firstName?: T;
  readonly lastName?: T;
}


class SortBy extends FindUserDto<'ASC' | 'DESC'> {

}
```

But I'd like to get a more reusable solution. Did someone try to make something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Record` type conjunction with `keyof T`. Using this `SortBy` will not be a class, it will be a type alias, and you can implement it using any object literal:

```
class FindUserDto {
    readonly _id?: string | object;
    readonly email?: string;
    readonly firstName?: string;
    readonly lastName?: string;
}

type SortBy = Record<keyof FindUserDto, 'ASC' | 'DESC'> 
// type SortBy = Record<Exclude<keyof FindUserDto, "_id">, 'ASC' | 'DESC'> // or remove _id 
let sortBy: SortBy = {
    _id: "ASC",
    email: "DESC",
    firstName: "DESC",
    lastName: "ASC"
}
```

Or you can implement it as a class as well, but you will have to re-declare the fields (although the compiler makes sure you re-declare them all):

```
class SortBy implements Record<keyof FindUserDto, 'ASC' | 'DESC' | undefined>  {
    _id: "ASC" | "DESC"| undefined;
    email: "ASC" | "DESC"| undefined;
    firstName: "ASC" | "DESC"| undefined;
    lastName: "ASC" | "DESC"| undefined;
}
```

If you don't re-declare all the fields, you can also create a dummy class that pretends to implement the fields for the benefit of the compiler:

```
function sortByClass<T>() : new () => Record<keyof T, 'ASC' | 'DESC' | undefined> {
    return class {} as any
}
class SortBy extends sortByClass<FindUserDto>() {
}
```

**Note:** Since the fields are not initialized, I added `| undefined` to the type of the fields in order to keep the field types in alignment with the actual possibilities. This matters only if you are using `stricyNullChecks`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FindUserDto {
  readonly _id?: string | object;
  readonly email?: string;
  readonly firstName?: string;
  readonly lastName?: string;
}

type Sortable <T> = {
   [P in keyof T]: 'ASC' | 'DESC';
};

let a: Sortable<FindUserDto>; 

a = { email: 'ASC', firstName: 'DESC', lastName: 'ASC' };

// a = { email: 'ASC', firstName: 'DESC', lastName: 'ASC123' }; //error
```

Here's another solution [with enums](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20SORT%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ASC%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20DESC%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FindUserDto%3CSORT%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20_id%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20object%3B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20email%3F%3A%20SORT%3B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20firstName%3F%3A%20SORT%3B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20lastName%3F%3A%20SORT%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20FindUserDto%3CSORT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20email%3A%20SORT.ASC%2C%20firstName%3A%20SORT.DESC%2C%20lastName%3A%20SORT.ASC%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: Thank you, Yakov. This one is good. I also tried to create a type, worked in fact. But for my current task I need a class to be declared. This is for processing nested validation by the class-validator library.

https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects

Comment: You can use keyof only with types.  I've updated my answer with the enum solution.